# Play sound when Tab is Active

Tags: javascript

Hello I have hear my script to play sound when Tab is not Active, how I can change this to play also when I'm on the Tab?

```
'document.addEventListener('chatLoaded', function(event) {
event.chat.audioControl.loadSoundFile('http://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/handbag-lock-4.mp3');
document.addEventListener('newMessage', function(event) {
    var chat = event.chat;
    if (!chat.isActiveTab()) {
        event.chat.audioControl.play();
    }
});
```

});'

Comment: Why can't you simply remove the check if `!chat.isActiveTab()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use focus() and blur() function to detect if tab is active or not. 
Or you can use page visibility API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but If I got your question right and when you said "tab" you meant the browser tab, that seems pretty simple to me. All you have to do is remove the if statement, then it'll play the sound every time the event is triggered:

```
document.addEventListener('newMessage', function(event) {
    event.chat.audioControl.play();
});
```

If with "tab" what you meant was an HTML element, you can use blur and focus events  to keep track of focusing state. In this case there's also solutions to check about user visibility in the browser tab, which Shota Noniashvili answer is covering.